# Zencart how to insert an image in my layout

Tags: php

I really just want to add a fixed image to my zencart shopping cart without going to the admin panel. I have tried normal  with no luck. I have also tried with the same issue.

I suspect there is a php function which gives me the correct page to my template folder, so if anyone knows how to do it please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a function to build it for me. Did not find one directly to use.